# PHP CURL script getting 502/503 server error after first couple of requests

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

I have been working on a clients WP site which lists deals from Groupon. I am using  the Groupon's official XML feed, importing via WP All Import. This works without much hassle. Now the issue is Groupon doesn't update that feed frequently but some of their deals get sold out or off the market often. So to get this resolved what I am trying is using a CURL script to crawl the links and check if the deal is available or not then turn the unavailable deals to draft posts (Once a day only).

The custom script is working almost perfectly, only after the first 14/24 requests the server starts responding with 502/503 HTTP status codes. To overcome the issue I have used the below precautions -

1. Using the proper header (captured from the requests made by the browser)
2. Parsing cookies from response header and sending back.
3. Using proper referrer and user agent.
4. Using proxies.
5. Trying to send request after a set interval. PHP - sleep(5);

Unfortunately, none of this got me the solution I wanted. I am attaching my code and I would like to request your expert insights on the issue, please.

Thanks in advance for your time.
Shahriar

PHP SCRIPT - https://pastebin.com/FF2cNm5q

```
<?php

// Error supressing and extend maximum execution time
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 50000);

// Sitemap URL List
$all_activity_urls = array();
$sitemap_url = array(
     'https://www.groupon.de/sitemaps/deals-local0.xml.gz'
);
$cookies = Array();

// looping through sitemap url for scraping activity urls
for ($u = 0; $u < count($sitemap_url); $u++)
{
     $ch1 = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
     curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0');
     curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://www.groupon.de/");
     curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);
//    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
     curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $sitemap_url[$u]);
     curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
     // Parsing Cookie from the response header
     curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, "curlResponseHeaderCallback");
     $activity_url_source = curl_exec($ch1);
     $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch1, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
     curl_close($ch1);

     if ($status_code === 200)
     {
          // Parsing XML sitemap for activity urls
          $activity_url_list = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($activity_url_source)));
          for ($a = 0; $a < count($activity_url_list->url); $a++)
          {
               array_push($all_activity_urls, $activity_url_list->url[$a]->loc);
          }
     }
}


if (count($all_activity_urls) > 0)
{
// URL Loop count
     $loop_from = 0;
     $loop_to = (count($all_activity_urls) > 0) ? 100 : 0;
//    $loop_to = count($all_activity_urls);

     $final_data = array();
     echo 'script start - ' . date('h:i:s') . "<br>";

     for ($u = $loop_from; $u < $loop_to; $u++)
     {
          //Pull source from webpage
          $headers = array(
               'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
               'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,bn-BD;q=0.8,bn;q=0.7,it;q=0.6',
               'cache-control: max-age=0',
               'cookie: ' . implode('; ', $cookies),
               'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1',
               'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'
          );

          $site = $all_activity_urls[$u];
          $ch = curl_init();
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://www.groupon.de/");
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
          // Parsing Cookie from the response header
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, "curlResponseHeaderCallback");
          $data = curl_exec($ch);
          $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
          curl_close($ch);

          if ($status_code === 200)
          {
               // Ready data for parsing
               $document = new DOMDocument();
               $document->loadHTML('<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">' . $data);
               $xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

               $title = '';     
               $availability = '';
               $price = '';
               $base_price = '';
               $link = '';
               $image = '';

               $link = $all_activity_urls[$u];

               // Scraping Availability
               $raw_availability = $xpath->query('//div[@data-bhw="DealHighlights"]/div[0]/div/div');
               $availability = $raw_availability->item(0)->nodeValue;

               // Scraping Title     
               $raw_title = $xpath->query('//h1[@id="deal-title"]');
               $title = $raw_title->item(0)->nodeValue;

               // Scraping Price
               $raw_price = $xpath->query('//div[@class="price-discount-wrapper"]');
               $price = trim(str_replace(array("$", "€", "US", "&nbsp;"), array("", "", "", ""), $raw_price->item(0)->nodeValue));

               // Scraping Old Price
               $raw_base_price = $xpath->query('//div[contains(@class, "value-source-wrapper")]');
               $base_price = trim(str_replace(array("$", "€", "US", "&nbsp;"), array("", "", "", ""), $raw_base_price->item(0)->nodeValue));

               // Creating Final Data Array
               array_push($final_data, array(
                    'link' => $link,
                    'availability' => $availability,
                    'name' => $title,
                    'price' => $price,
                    'baseprice' => $base_price,
                    'img' => $image,
               ));
          }
          else
          {
               $link = $all_activity_urls[$u];
               if ($status_code === 429)
               {
                    $status_msg = ' - Too Many Requests';
               }
               else
               {
                    $status_msg = '';
               }

               array_push($final_data, array(
                    'link' => $link,
                    'status' => $status_code . $status_msg,
               ));
          }
          echo 'before break - ' . date('h:i:s') . "<br>";
          sleep(5);
          echo 'after break - ' . date('h:i:s') . "<br>";
          flush();
     }
     echo 'script end - ' . date('h:i:s') . "<br>";
     // Converting data to XML
     $activities = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><activities></activities>");
     array_to_xml($final_data, $activities);
     $xml_file = $activities->asXML('activities.xml');
     if ($xml_file)
     {
          echo 'XML file have been generated successfully.';
     }
     else
     {
          echo 'XML file generation error.';
     }
}
else
{
     $activities = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><activities></activities>");
     $activities->addChild("error", htmlspecialchars("No URL scraped from sitemap. Stoping script."));
     $xml_file = $activities->asXML('activities.xml');
     if ($xml_file)
     {
          echo 'XML file have been generated successfully.';
     }
     else
     {
          echo 'XML file generation error.';
     }
}

// Recursive Function for creating XML Nodes
function array_to_xml($array, &$activities)
{
     foreach ($array as $key => $value)
     {
          if (is_array($value))
          {
               if (!is_numeric($key))
               {
                    $subnode = $activities->addChild("$key");
                    array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
               }
               else
               {
                    $subnode = $activities->addChild("activity");
                    array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
               }
          }
          else
          {
               $activities->addChild("$key", htmlspecialchars("$value"));
          }
     }
}

// Cookie Parsing Function
function curlResponseHeaderCallback($ch, $headerLine)
{
     global $cookies;
     if (preg_match('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $headerLine, $cookie) == 1)
     {
          $cookies[] = $cookie[1];
     }
     return strlen($headerLine); // Needed by curl
}
```

Comment: Sounds a little bit like a lightweight DOS attack. :) Have you tried `sleep` / `usleep` to have a delay between requests? You might be temporarily locked out.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone I think I do realize it now and I am really sorry about that.I wish I never had to do this only if they updated the XML feed atleast once a day. The major issue is client is re-selling the deals. Unfortunately if he sells an unavailable deal and fail to deliver, that will going to cause him a lot of trouble. This is the only reason we have to take the drastic measure.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone Yes I ahve already tried putting a 5 second delay between the request 

"sleep(5);"

But getting the same error.

Comment: 24 is not that much, webpages have similar resource loads linked. However, the server could lockout subsequent page requests within a short period for security reasons. - Ok, 5 sec., so we can exclude that.

Comment: Does this also happen when you start with the 14th request immediately? You should try to reduce the test case to the part having an issue, e.g. writing a single hardcoded request which is easier to debug and reproduce.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone Yes I do agree with you. Seems like " the server could lockout subsequent page requests within a short period for security reasons" makes more sense. Now All I just want to make sure that 

"I have done everything that is possible with PHP" to resolve this issue and no stones unturned, so that I can give my client a final report. He is thinking of turning to Python

Comment: You could try to change cookies and other identification characteristics as far as possible.

Comment: Actually, every time when I run the script it starts to throw 503 after the 14th request. i have tried requesting with 1 single request and that gets passed easily. Infact it goes till the 14th request made to the server without any issue.

Comment: But first try to loop from `$u = 13`.

Comment: I am already parsing the set cookie parameter from the response header and using the new cookie for the next request. I have even tried using proxy on rotation.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting to loop from the 13th. let try it now and get back in 10-15 mins top.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone Unfortunately, the result is same. Just got blocked out after the 14th request. Still thanks for suggesting every possible thing to try. :)

Comment: Good news, I joined the DDoS attack :D It seems to work even without any delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mess of cookies in your snippet. The callback function just appends cookies to the array regardingless of whether they already exist or not. Here is a new version which at least seems to work in this case since there are no semicolon-seperated multiple cookie definitions. Usually the cookie string should be even parsed. If you have installed the http extension you can use `http_parse_cookie`.

```
// Cookie Parsing Function
function curlResponseHeaderCallback($ch, $headerLine)
{
  global $cookies;

  if (preg_match('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]+)/mi', $headerLine, $match) == 1)
  {

    if(false !== ($p = strpos($match[1], '=')))
    {
      $replaced = false;
      $cname    = substr($match[1], 0, $p+1);

      foreach ($cookies as &$cookie)
        if(0 === strpos($cookie, $cname))
        {
          $cookie = $match[1];
          $replaced = true;
          break;
        }

      if(!$replaced)
        $cookies[] = $match[1];
    }
var_dump($cookies);
  }
  return strlen($headerLine); // Needed by curl
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your revised code. Let me check and get back to you within 10-15 mins tops.

Comment: Sir you are a life saver. It worked like a charm. :) Thank You very much